# How to paginate invoices from stripe in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

I want to paginate my invoices from stripe. I tried to do so with `new Paginator` in my controller.

Controller

```
$invoices = auth()->user()->invoices();
$invoices = new Paginator($invoices, 1);

$invoices->withPath('/settings/invoices');
```

Passed my $invoices variable to the view created pagination links like so

```
{{ $invoices->links() }}
```

The problem no invoices are loaded if I paginate. The page stays always the same...
Maybe someone could help me here?

Output
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array = auth()->user()->invoices()->toArray();
      $total= count($array);
      $per_page = 10;
      $current_page = $request->input("page") ?? 1;
      $starting_point = ($current_page * $per_page) - $per_page;
      $array = array_slice($array, $starting_point, $per_page, true);

      $invoices = new Paginator($array, $total, $per_page, $current_page, [
          'path' => $request->url(),
          'query' => $request->query(),
      ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the first item that should pass to Paginator class should be a collection, But you are passing the whole query to it. so it should be something like

```
$invoices = new Paginator(auth()->user()->invoices, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but problem persists and I have to say I dont understand whats the difference to my code?

Comment: You can track the $invoice object from the controller, Check if it contains the pagination. Then go to your blade file and check it there.

Comment: No it does not contain the pagination, but why?

Comment: Lets chat here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214532/how-to-paginate-invoices-from-stripe-in-laravel

Answer (score 0):

```
   use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

   $invoices = auth()->user()->invoices();
   $invoices = new Paginator($invoices, 10);
   $invoices->setPath($request->url());
```

Comment: Please add appropriate description to your answer